# Updating a library file to multiple locations in Linux

Tags: linux, file, versions

I've got a library file that I often access, as you would, from the library.  eg `/library/component.js`  But sometimes that needs to be accessed as a copy in a project folder.  eg. `.../someProject/library/component.js`

My problem is that if I update the master version of `component.js` I want the many project versions updated also.   I don't know where all the project copies are except they do have one root directory which for this discussion let's call `/projects`.

The algorithm is:

(1) Search for `component.js` in all sub-dirs of `/projects`.

(2) Update with master file if newer

(Other build and update functions such as FTP are outside the scope, but a log would be nice.)

Q1: Is there a Linux utility that will snap into action?

Q2: Can anyone suggest a shell script?

(I can do clever MS-DOS batch scripts but I'm a novice when it comes to the Linux command line.)

Comment: I think this sort of question may be better answered on SuperUser (http://superuser.com/) rather than Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

If the files you are trying to update, are not created and deleted frequently, you can use locate command.

> (1) Search for component.js in all sub-dirs of /projects. (Use *locate component.js*)

Then you may make use of *rsync* to update those files one by one. Maybe by traversing the output of the locate command.

p.s.

If you couldn't locate your files, just run "*updatedb*" command once.

Answer (score 0):

> (1) Search for `component.js` in all sub-dirs of `/projects`.
>
> (2) Update with master file if newer
>
> (Other build and update functions such as FTP are outside the scope,
>   but a log would be nice.)
>
> Q1: Is there a Linux utility that will snap into action?

Yes, it's called [`find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

```
find /projects -name component.js ! -newer /library/component.js -exec cp /library/component.js {} \;
```

For a log we can add the option `-v` after `cp` and redirect the output.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.